# What was the name of the Sage in the story narrated by Sita?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, indra

Sita narrated an old episode about a Sage(Rishi) to Sri Rama, in the Dandaka forest.The narration is as under:-

> Once upon a time, oh, dexterous one, there was a pious and true worded hermit in some merited forest that was inhabited by animals and birds.
>   Then Indra came to that hermitage handling a sword, and donning a soldier's guise, to cause hindrance to that hermit's ascesis.
>   Indra gave that best sword to store, there in that hermitage, to that sage who is lasting in his ascesis, on a redeemable basis.
>   On receiving that sword, he who is duteous in guarding the entrustment, moved about in the forest always handling the sword, to safeguard the confidence reposed in him.
>   Wherever that dedicated guardian of that entrustment went, even to obtain tubers or fruits, he did not go without that sword.
>   Carrying that sword always, that hermit slowly made his own faculty infuriated, loosing determination in ascesis.
>   Then with the constant association of that weapon that sage gradually became inadvertent, and smitten by vice he went to hell(i.e. the sage did not go to the place that he earlier fully deserved to go viz Heaven)

From [Aranya Kanda sarga 9](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga9/aranya_9_prose.htm)

Is this story mentioned in the Puranas(or other scriptures)? What was the name of the Rishi (Sage) in the story narrated by Sita?